# Can´t make content show after hovering div

Tags: html, css

I would like an explanation on why my thought process on this isn't working. I know there are many other ways of doing what i'm trying to achieve, but i just want to understand why it fails. I would like the content of the `"downmenu"` show after i hover the `"rightside"`.

```css
    .rightside{
        background-color: transparent;
        border: none;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px; bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 95px; 
        transition: 2s;
    }
    .hoverdrop{
        background-color: transparent;
        color: gray;
        font-size: 22px;
        border: none;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: fixed;
        top: 0px; bottom: 0px;
        right: 0px;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 95px; 
       
        
        
    }
    .rightside :hover > .langcontent{
        visibility: visible;
        opacity: 1;
    
    }
    .langcontent{
        visibility: hidden;
        opacity: 0;
        position: fixed;
        right: 0px;
        top: 83px;
        background-color: transparent;
        min-width: 95px;
        text-align: center;
        overflow: hidden;
        height: 30px;
        transition: 2s;   
    }
    .langcontent a{
        font-size: 22px;
        color: gray;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }
```

```html
<div class="rightside">
                            <button class="hoverdrop">ENG
                            </button>
                            <div id="downmenu" class="langcontent">
                                <a href="esp.html">ESP</a>
                            </div>     
                </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a space in `.rightside :hover`. It should be `.rightside:hover`.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lgb1sxqf/

Comment: Wow, you are right! Thank you so much, have a good day.